# Calculate battery duration

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, low-battery

Maybe this is a trivial question, but I am struggling with it for a while.

I have an alkaline AA battery which is consuming 80mA for 8 seconds each 30 minutes. I need to calculate how many days it will last before reaching 1.1v. I know it depends a lot on the battery type, but let's say it is a Duracell battery.

I have problems in calculating the "average" consumption per hour, as the battery is drained for just 8 seconds (80mA) each 30 minutes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ Fabio This is an energy question. Compute the energy consumed each hour. (amp*seconds). And examine the typical amp*hours of your chosen battery size (e.g 1 amp*hour).

Comment: Yes, thanks. But this would give me time to discharge. I need to compute "time to 1.1 volts"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average current is given by

$$ I_{AVG} = \frac {80m  \times 8}{30 \times 60} = 0.35 \ \text {mA} $$

[image]

*Figure 1. The Duracell [AA Plus Power](http://professional.duracell.com/downloads//datasheets/product/Plus%20Power/Plus_AA_MN1500.pdf) quotes for currents down to 5 mA continuous.*

This shows that at 5 mA you can expect > 500 hours. You'll have to extrapolate for your load conditions.

Comment: Can you pls explain the formula? What is the "6" at the numerator? What is 60x30 at the denominator?

Comment: My error, I'm afraid. It should have been the 8 seconds on time. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If the average current is 0.35mA I should expect a lot more than 500 hours. Isn't it?

Comment: Correct, but there are no figures published. There's a Battery University site that may have some figures. Do a search.